# Как получить процент значение между минимальным и максимальным значением?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить

Минимальное значение: 112.44, где оно 0%

Максимальное значение: 574.37, где оно 100%

Нужно узнать какой процент между ними имеет значение 385.45

Примерную схему нарисовал

```
112.44 ---- 385.45 ----- 574.37
0% ---------- ?% ------- 100%

let result = ?
```

```js
let obj = {0: "448.14", 1: "112.44", 2: "244.91", 3: "174.02", 4: "198.74",  5: "302.78", 6: "574.37", 7: "434.01", 8: "439.74"};
let val = 385.45;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

примерно вот так:

```
const percent = 100 * (value - min) / (max - min);

const percent = (max == min) ? 0 : (100 * (value - min) / (max - min));
```

Comment: И небольшой сюрпиз, когда `max==min`

Comment: @teran, ну дополнительную проверку можно повесить, но скажите когда `max==min`, то чему равняется промежуточное значение? 0 или 100? :) Как по мне такая ситуация чуть раньше должна обрабатываться, но код все таки обносил